# Is HeadTracker deprecated?

Tags: android, google-vr

I've been using the HeadTracker class in the Google VR sdk's base library to run some audio tests. However, I can't find any documentation for it anywhere on the Google VR SDK's docs. Is using this class currently discouraged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the [Google VR SDK for Android v0.8.0](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/release-notes#google_vr_sdk_for_android_v080) made:

> Packages have been migrated from com.google.vrtoolkit. to com.google.vr.sdk.. The com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard package is now com.google.vr.sdk.base.

The [HeadTracker](https://github.com/raasun/cardboard/blob/master/src/com/google/vrtoolkit/cardboard/sensors/HeadTracker.java) class was in package com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.sensors and can be found on GitHub [https://github.com/Zomega/Cardboard](https://github.com/Zomega/Cardboard/blob/master/src/com/google/vrtoolkit/cardboard/sensors/HeadTracker.java)

But it's gone.

But I belive that they do some refactoring, just look how similar NDK version is to original HeadTracker [NDK head tracking](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/ndk/reference/group/headtracking). [HeadTracker was eaten, but it is somewhere.](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/reference/com/google/vr/sdk/base/GvrView.html#recenterHeadTracker())

Does it make it deprecated? It's old, undocumented and it propably won't be easy to rewrite so I guess it is deprecated.

The new way of tracking is to use HeadTransform. Take a look on this example [GitHub link](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/sdk-treasurehunt/src/main/java/com/google/vr/sdk/samples/treasurehunt/TreasureHuntActivity.java) especially on method `onNewFrame(HeadTransform headTransform)`

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Do you need to implement a GvrRenderer to get a HeadTransform out of the GVR SDK?